# The verb tense after "it is possible"

Tags: subjunctives

Is it

> It is possible that several rules **be matched** by visiting a node

Or

> It is possible that several rules **are matched** by visiting a node

In Persian, after "its possible that" a subjunctive form is used, I want to know if it is the case of English too or not?

Comment: Either one is fine. In the first, use of the subjunctive makes it sound a bit more formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I prefer children be seen and not heard
>
> Is it possible that dinner be served before we all die of malnutrition (or worse, run out of booze)?

As Robusto says, this is grammatical, but slightly more formal. It's not a common construction, and I would recommend against using it in an academic paper, but it can be used for fun to say something ordinary in a different way.

As a side note: The subjunctive can be used if you want to sound like a pirate:

> Arr, it be true that several rules be matched by visiting a node, matey!

[Why "pirate talk" sounds like that](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/09/19/pirate_speech_origins_in_west_country_english_via_robert_newton_aka_long.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the present subjunctive there, but most people would add either the modal "may" or "might" before the "be" in Modern English:

'It is possible that several rules **might be** matched by visiting a node."

Comment: No one under 85 uses *be* here.